# sort output of describe-instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

I saw the previous question on this topic, but the answer was just "pipe it to a scripting language!", which I find unsatisfying.   I know that JMESPath has `sort_by`, and `sort`, but I can't figure out how to use them.

I have

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
   --filters "Name=tag:Group,Values=production" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" "Name=tag:Name,Values=prod-*-${CURRENT_SHA}-*" \
   --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[LaunchTime,InstanceId,PrivateIpAddress,Tags[?Key==`Name`] | [0].Value]' \
   --output table
```

And it outputs the right data, just in a random order.  I want to sort by the last column of the data, Tag Name, aka `` Tags[?Key==`Name`] ``, which in raw form looks like this:

```
{
  "Tags": [{
    "Value": "application-server-ab3634b34364a-2",
    "Key": "Name"
  }, {
    "Value": "production",
    "Key": "Group"
  }]
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Since JMESPath is evaluated against JSON data, please write the `Tags` line in JSON format, not Python. That is: `{"Tags": [{"Value": "application-server-ab3634b34364a-2", "Key": "Name"}, {"Value": "production", "Key": "Group"}]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to add `| sort_by(@, &@[0][3])`

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --filters "Name=tag:Group,Values=production" "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" "Name=tag:Name,Values=prod-*-${CURRENT_SHA}-*" \
  --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[LaunchTime,InstanceId,PrivateIpAddress,Tags[?Key==`Name`] | [0].Value]| sort_by(@, &@[0][3])' \
  --output table
```

Comment: So in fact you've got a *list of tables* instead of just one table. No? I mean, something like this: `[[ "<R1,I1>", "<R1,I2>" ],[ "<R2,I1>", "<R2,I2>" ]]` where `R1`/`R2` and `I1/I2` mean *Reservation 1/2* and *Instance 1/2*, respectively. Please clarify your question. Don't you want to flatten the tables into one table? Right now you are sorting the tables themselves by the `TagName` of each table's first entry.

Comment: /shrug   I'm not very familiar with aws ec2, I just pasted the actual query we are using.   The final answer I pasted does indeed generate exactly the output I wanted.   In the end, I see tables whose rows are sorted by the last column in the table, which is all I wanted.

Comment: Okay, I checked the aws ec2 docs, and it's indeed a ”list of tables“. I've updated my answer. I think `| sort_by(@, &@[0][3])` is *not* the correct answer, because it will sort the ”list of tables“ by the `TagName` of each table's first row (!).

Answer (score 30):

## short answer

add

```
[] | sort_by(@, &[3])
```

at the end of your expression. The brackets (`[]`) will flatten the structure, `sort_by(...)` will sort the result (which is a four-column table) by the fourth column. The full query will be:

```
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[LaunchTime,InstanceId,PrivateIpAddress,Tags[?Key==`Name`] | [0].Value][] | sort_by(@, &[3])'
```

## long answer

### inspecting your current query result

According to the [`describe-instances` docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html), the structure of the `describe-instances` output looks like this:

```
{
  "Reservations": [
    {
      "Instances": [
        {
          "LaunchTime": "..LaunchTime..",
          "InstanceId": "R1I1",
          "PrivateIpAddress": "..PrivateIpAddress..",
          "Tags": [{"Key": "Name", "Value": "foo"}]
        },
        {
          "LaunchTime": "..LaunchTime..",
          "InstanceId": "R1I2",
          "PrivateIpAddress": "..PrivateIpAddress..",
          "Tags": [{"Key": "Name", "Value": "baz"}]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Instances": [
        {
          "LaunchTime": "..LaunchTime..",
          "InstanceId": "R2I1",
          "PrivateIpAddress": "..PrivateIpAddress..",
          "Tags": [{"Key": "Name", "Value": "bar"}]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Using your original query

```
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[LaunchTime,InstanceId,PrivateIpAddress,Tags[?Key==`Name`] | [0].Value]'
```

will output

```
[
  [
    [
      "..LaunchTime..",
      "R1I1",
      "..PrivateIpAddress..",
      "foo"
    ],
    [
      "..LaunchTime..",
      "R1I2",
      "..PrivateIpAddress..",
      "baz"
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "..LaunchTime..",
      "R2I1",
      "..PrivateIpAddress..",
      "bar"
    ]
  ]
]
```

### flattening the query result

You can see in the above result of your query that you're getting a list of tables (`[[{},{}],[{}]]`). I suppose you instead want a single non-nested table (`[{},{},{}]`). To achieve that, simply add `[]` at the end of your query, i.e.

```
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[LaunchTime,InstanceId,PrivateIpAddress,Tags[?Key==`Name`] | [0].Value][]'
```

This will flatten the structure, resulting in

```
[
  [
    "..LaunchTime..",
    "R1I1",
    "..PrivateIpAddress..",
    "foo"
  ],
  [
    "..LaunchTime..",
    "R1I2",
    "..PrivateIpAddress..",
    "baz"
  ],
  [
    "..LaunchTime..",
    "R2I1",
    "..PrivateIpAddress..",
    "bar"
  ]
]
```

Now it's time to sort the table.

### sorting the table

When using `sort_by` you shouldn't forget to prepend the expression by `&` (ampersand). This way you specify a *reference* to that expression, which is then passed to `sort_by`.

**example:** `data | sort_by(@, &@)` is equivalent to `data | sort(@)`.

The `TagName` in the table you create (`[LaunchTime,InstanceId,PrivateIpAddress,TagName]`) is the fourth column. You can get that column by piping the table to the expression `[3]`:

```
TableExpression | [3]
```

But instead, you want to **sort** the table by the fourth column. You can do so like this:

```
TableExpression | sort_by(@, &[3])
```

and the resulting query will be:

```
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[LaunchTime,InstanceId,PrivateIpAddress,Tags[?Key==`Name`][] | [0].Value] | sort_by(@, &[3])'
```

Query result:

```
[
  [
    "..LaunchTime..",
    "R2I1",
    "..PrivateIpAddress..",
    "bar"
  ],
  [
    "..LaunchTime..",
    "R1I2",
    "..PrivateIpAddress..",
    "baz"
  ],
  [
    "..LaunchTime..",
    "R1I1",
    "..PrivateIpAddress..",
    "foo"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, you got me close, it was actually
`TableExpression | sort_by(@, &@[0][3])`

Answer (score 6):

As an enhancement to @ColinK's answer, I wanted to sort a table that had custom column headers but struggled with the syntax.  I eventually got it to work so I thought I'd share in case someone else wanted to do the same.  I added a column for State and sorted by that column.

```
--query 'sort_by(Reservations[*].Instances[*].{LaunchTime:LaunchTime, ID:InstanceId,IP:PrivateIpAddress,State:State.Name,Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`] | [0].Value}[], &State)'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Adding link to the jmespath documentation (which aws cli uses) of sort_by function for reference https://jmespath.org/examples.html#sort-by

Answer (score 3):

Here is an other example that works also:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value,Instance:InstanceId} | sort_by(@, &[0].Name)'
```

Comment: This kinda worked for my needs, but it failed when the Name value is "None"